# How to implement authentication in Asp.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

All , After I read [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528900/why-request-isauthenticated-is-false), I had some idea of implement user login and authentication in Asp.net MVC4. I hope someone can help to review this. **Any comments or other solutions are  welcome.** Thanks.

Firstly,I would use a viewbag variable to determine whether it is a authenticated request in the view.
the code should be something like:

```
<% if (ViewData["longined"] == "success")
   { %>
    //display something shows user already logged in. 
<%}%>
```

Then Implement a global filter to check authenticated user info which can be retrieve from session. If this user info does exist in session,That means the user doesn't log in. otherwise should set 
`ViewData["longined"] == "success"`.

In the login action and view . I can fill the user name and password in the view, and post to an `Action` to validate them. If success I would store the user info in the session.

The last thing need to do is registering global filter in `Global.asax`. thanks.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't want to use cookies, the `[Authorize]` attribute, `Request.IsAuthenticated`, etc?

Comment: Hi, HTX9 .Any other solutions are welcome. I will up vote them. thanks.