# Request.IsAuthenticated returns false unless page refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

As a part of my user logon/logoff process of my webpage (using standard MVC authentication module) I have the following on my view:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //logoff
}
else
{
    //logon
}
```

However, when my user logs in successfully and return to that page (view) back, the `Request.IsAuthentgicated` getter is `false` unless I refresh my page and then it equals to `true` and works as expected.

Can anyone explain why is that so and how it can be fixed without having to reload my page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Request.IsAuthenticated is false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528900/why-request-isauthenticated-is-false). It basically comes down to the fact that when the request is made (the POST in the login form), the user was not authenticated due the lack of an authentication cookie.

Comment: The other question doesn't fully suggest how this issue can be solved, though. Any ideas?

Comment: The answer of the question suggests to create a view model with a property determining whether the request is authenticated rather than using `Request.IsAuthenticated`. After a successful login you could set the property explicitly to `true`. I'm - however - not sure how to implement this. Perhaps you need something like a base view model.

Answer (score 4):

The `Request.IsAuthenticated` property will be false for the request that actually performs the login; after all, the user was unauthenticated at the time of the request.

So it's what you'd expect and just highlights that a slight change in the login process is needed. Instead of rendering the view in the Response to the login, perform a redirect instead (exactly how ASP.NET Web Forms does it) ... a `RedirectResult` instead of a `ViewResult`

Therefore:

1. GET home page

   - Request.IsAuthenticated == false
2. GET Login

   - Request.IsAuthenticated == false
3. POST Login (actually authenticate)

   - Request.IsAuthenticated == false
   - Response contains auth cookie and is a redirect to home page (HTTP 302)
4. GET home page

   - Request now has auth cookie
   - Request.IsAuthenticated == true

I